# GetForegroundWindow и GetFocus - выдают разные дескрипторы

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибаюсь:

GetForegroundWindow - возвращает дескриптор того окна, который находится на переднем плане и имеет фокус клавиатуры, и если на переднем плане находится окно не имеющее фокуса клавиатуры, то функция вернет дескриптор окна, которое имеет фокус клавиатуры.

GetFfocus - возвращает дескриптор того окна, на котором в данный момент фокус клавиатуры.

Я запускаю код с этими двумя функциями ставлю задержку 10 секунд - открываю обычный текстовый файл и смотрю какие дескрипторы выдадут эти функции. И они выдают разные дескрипторы:

```
Sleep(10000);

 HWND my_HWND_ = GetForegroundWindow();
 std::cout << my_HWND_ << std::endl;



 DWORD dwTargetOwner = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), NULL);
 DWORD dwThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId(); //указатель на текущий процесс

 AttachThreadInput(dwTargetOwner, dwThreadID,TRUE);    //Приаттачиваю потоки

 HWND my_HWND__ = GetFocus();
 std::cout << my_HWND__ << std::endl;
```

Я ожидал увидеть одинаковые дескрипторы, но они разные. Вот и думаю где я ошибаюсь ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetForegroundWindow` возвращает дескриптор окна верхнего уровня (т.е. не дочернего), которое сейчас находится на переднем плане. `GetFocus` возвращает дескриптор окна (в т.ч. дочернего), использующего очередь сообщений текущего потока и владеющего фокусом клавиатуры.

Comment: user7860670, но в моем случае разве это не одно и тоже окно блокнота ?

Comment: @Optimus1 Нет, у блокнота несколько дочерних окон, в т.ч. вся область с текстом.